# How to hide all dired buffers in ibuffer?

Tags: dired, ibuffer

I want to hide all Dired buffers as major mode in Ibuffer.

But

```
(add-to-list 'ibuffer-never-show-predicates "magit*")
```

`ibuffer-never-show-predicates` accepts a regexp and a function.

How can I hide all Dired buffers in Ibuffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can write a predicate function for that:

```el
(defun my-dired-mode-buffer-p (buf)
  "Non-nil if buffer BUF is in `dired-mode'."
  (with-current-buffer buf
    (derived-mode-p 'dired-mode)))

(with-eval-after-load "ibuffer"
  (add-to-list 'ibuffer-never-show-predicates #'my-dired-mode-buffer-p))
```

Comment: It works. thank you.

Comment: OP: If this answers your question then please consider accepting this answer. That way the question will no longer appear among the unanswered questions. Thx.